# Trivial BigQuery query returns `Resources exceeded during query execution`

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a ~180GB table partitioned by day on the `dt` column. I try to run the following query on the table, which BigQuery estimates will process 2.6GB:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `fafalytics.misc.cmds_q122` WHERE dt = "2022-01-30" AND id = "16247735"
```

I'd expect this to be a straightforward query, but it fails with
`Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 102% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): input table/file scan: 99% other/unattributed: 1%` and I don't understand why.

The only thing unusual about this table is that I'm registered to the JSON native data type Preview, and the table has a large-ish JSON column - approximately 1K per row. I mention it because I'm not sure what's going on, but I don't think it's related to the problem.

As you can see, there is no `ORDER BY` or other load-in-memory operations; why does the query fail?

Comment: Hi @YanivAknin, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Hey @Yaniv, we have the exact same issue, could you find any solution to yours=

Comment: @intacto, sorry, no. It's not a very important query for me, but it still reproduces.